# Applying restrictions to Grails Searchable results

Tags: grails, grails-searchable

I'm developing an application with Grails 2.2.2 / MySQL.

I'd like to integrate the Searchable plugin, however my application is a multi-tenant saas app, and I need to restrict the results that are returned somehow. So for instance if I am a user of my application belonging to organisation A and I search for products, I should not see any products that belong to organisation B.

I currently have a service that carries out this kind of data partitioning when using the regular grails CRUD pages which works by applying restrictions to every criteria query executed. I've also integrated this service with the Filterpane plugin, for 'advanced search' style queries.

Is it possible to filter Searchable results in a similar way?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but my friends nad simillar problem with multitenancy and they have used 'Elastic search' plugin instead of 'searchable'. I don't know the correct solution but maybe you should do some research about this way ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I looked into this, but I did come across an interesting article about partitioning a lucene index so that 1) there is one index for the application and 2) search results for organisation A are not biased in any way by the stuff that has been indexed for organisation B (I didn't even consider that second point).

https://community.jivesoftware.com/community/developer/blog/2013/06/24/a-new-experimental-approach-to-implement-multi-tenancy-with-lucene-4

Also, for my application, I've *sort of* met the 'full text searching' requirement (for the short term at least) by using the excellent [Quick Search plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quick-search) for grails.

Hopefully someone will find these resources useful.